# protractor unable to click input='button' value

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm new to protractor and i was learning it and was struck in place.
I'm having a form with submit as shown below.

```
<input type="button" value="SIGN UP" class="btn btn-success btn-small" data-ng-click="ChceckMe()" />
```

I tried following ways but could not figure out

```
element(by.css('.btn-form')).click();
element(by.css('.btn .btn-success .btn-sm .btn-form')).click();
element(by.css('[ng-click="redirectRegister()"]')).click();
element.getAttribute('LOGIN').submit();
```

All of them throws error.....please help me out and any help is much appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing has the `.btn-form` class, or the `ng-click="redirectRegister()"` attribute, or the `'LOGIN'` attribute. None of your selectors correspond even remotely to your element. What do you expect to happen?

`'.btn .btn-success .btn-sm .btn-form'` is not a list of elements, it's a parent > child > child > child selector. You want `'.btn.btn-success.btn-sm.btn-form'` instead.

And `ChceckMe()` ?

Just try a selector that makes sense like `element(by.css('input.btn-success'))`.

Comment: Well I must admit it was pretty obvious :)